# Why the containValue method returning true even if i override the hashCode() method?

Tags: java, hashcode

HI even here if I comment out overridden hashcode method in the below code, the output is true for containValue method even the hashcodes are different please help with this. I had overridden equals method, but facing problem with containValue function.

```
import java.util.*; 
class Test{
    int i;
    Test(int i)
    {
        this.i=i;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object t)//overriding equals class
    {
        if(this.i==((Test)t).i){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    /*public int hashCode() { //overriding the hashcode method
    int result = 17; 
    result = 37*result + Integer.toString(i).hashCode(); 
    result = 37*result; 
    return result; 
    }*/
} 
class TestCollection13{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        HashMap<Integer,Test> hm=new HashMap<Integer,Test>();  
        hm.put(1,new Test(1));  
        hm.put(2,new Test(2));  
        hm.put(3,new Test(1));  
        hm.put(4,new Test(4));  
        for(Map.Entry m:hm.entrySet()){  
            Test t2=(Test)m.getValue();
            System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+t2.hashCode());  
        }
    System.out.println(hm.containsValue(new Test(1)));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to indent your code - it's very confusing at the moment. Note that when you're indenting everything by four spaces (as you should for blocks of code) you don't want/need the backticks.

Comment: your key is `Integer` not `Test`

Comment: because you have got an instance of `Test` in your `HashMap` with the value of `i` beeing `1`. Though the value exists in your `HashMap`

Comment: You implementation of equals for Test is plain wrong. You can't assume that the argument given to equals() can be safely cast to class Test. Plus: **do not use** static mains to test your code. Write unit tests; and put asserts in there. Using **static main** for testing is like 1999.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hash maps only use hash codes to find *keys* efficiently. When you ask the map to find a *value*, it basically has to iterate over all its entries, at which point there's no point in using `hashCode()`, so it just calls `equals`.

If you try the map the other way round, with `Test` as the key instead of the value, that *won't* work without overriding `hashCode`.